# Image Blur - Disc Kernel

Tags: r, spatial, kernel-smoothing, image-processing, spatstat

I'm trying to use the `blur()` function from the `spatstat` package in `R` to blur an image. One of the parameters that can be specified is `kernel` and as per the [help page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/spatstat/versions/1.64-1/topics/blur) for `blur()` one of the options for `kernel` is 'disc'.

I'm wondering if anyone can drop a link to an explanation of a disc kernel in this context. I've been unable to find a definition for the concept.

Thanks!

Comment: Almost surely it is a uniform kernel.

Comment: Appears to be it originates from [kernel2dmeitsjer](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/smoothie/versions/1.0-3/topics/kernel2dmeitsjer). "..“disk” gives a circular averaging (pill-box) kernel (aka, disk kernel). Similar to “average” or “boxcar”, but this kernel accounts for a specific distance in all directions from the center (i.e., an average of grid squares within a circular radius of the central point). This results in the convolution radius smoothing applied in Davis et al. (2006a,2006b). Requires that r (the desired radius) be supplied..."

Comment: A simple, reliable way to answer such questions in *any* computing platform is to construct a "unit impulse" or "Green's function" image where all but one pixel equals zero and the remaining pixel -- preferably near the middle -- has a unit value.  The resulting "blur" is an image of the kernel.

Comment: Thanks for the answers all! @whuber, thanks for the 'unit impulse' idea. I will give that a try.